# Problem in understanding of a sentence in a conversation

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is a conversation from a "*BBC Learning English*" YouTube video:

**Feifei**: We sometimes put the word "straight" in front of "fire". "Straight" here means "very".

**Roy**: So I probably should have said your T-shirt is straight fire, then.

Feifei: ***Only if that's what you really think!***

Do that sentence in bold mean "If you say so"? Or is there any other way to say that more naturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "Only say my T-shirt is straight fire if you really think my T-shirt is straight fire".

It is not really equivalent to "If you say so".  Idiomatically, this expression implies a sort of sarcastic disagreement.

> Peter: This T-shirt is excellent.
>   Jane: If you say so.

Here for example, the implication is that Jane does not think the T-shirt is excellent.

Comment: Can I say " If you really think so" instead of that sentence in bold?

Comment: "If you really think so" *might* be interpreted the same way as "If you say so".  You could say "Only if you really think so" - in my opinion that carries the same meaning as Feifei's sentence.  The word "only" is quite critical to Feifei's overall meaning.